# File is not accessible - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, webdriver, automated-tests

I have downloaded Visual Studio 2017/Community, for test automation, but when I added the reference selenium-dotnet 3.14.0 , it's saying that this file is not accessible.

Please help. Thanks

[click here to see the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmvSt.png)

Comment: You need to provide an example we can replicate. We can't help you unless you give us more.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The question by itself doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Could you give some context?

Comment: I am trying to configure visual studio for running automated tests, I downloaded c# version from Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings at seleniumhq.com but when I want to add it to my project, I get that error

Comment: @nicomp I added a screenshot, if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to the NuGet Package Manager?

Go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution

Then Search for Selenium and v3.14.0 is at the top

You can also do this from the NuGet Package Manager Console with:

```
Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver
```

Comment: Yes, but still not working. I tried so many ways, created new unit projects etc, but still nothing

Comment: What type of c# project are you working with? i.e. .net core, .net framework etc.

Comment: Unit Project, for testing with selenium webdriver

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot, you're trying to add a NuGet package through the "Add reference" dialog, which is designed to add references to DLLs directly. NuGet packages typically contain DLLs but you have to install them using the Manage NuGet Packages for Solution dialog as @ZP123 explained and not through Add Reference.